# Howto interop between vb.net and c (.dll) char* and structs*

Tags: vb.net, pointers, dll, interop, marshalling

How can i accomplish this interop between c and vb.net?

In my vb.net code i need to call some c functions from a .dll,

the c function looks like
`int __stdcall foo (someStruct* myStructure, char* myString )`

The myString gets filled in the c function, and i need the text from myString on the vb.net side

best regards

Comment: Ok it seems to work when i pass some intptrs and use the unmarshal methods

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to pass a string back would be to use a pre-allocated StringBuilder on the .NET side.  Structures work fine too, generally speaking, you just have to define them in .NET.  If you post your structure definition we may be able to assist with that.